# Wordpress Admin delete update-nag for user

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, panel

I want to hide/delete the update notification of WordPress v4.9.1 from administration panel.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `functions.php`.

```
function hide_update_nag_admin()
{
    if (current_user_can('update_core')) {
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'hide_update_nag_admin', 1 );
```

The function checks to see if the current user has permission to update the core, if they do, then remove the update nag from the admin. We then add the hook into the `admin_notices` function.

Here's some reading about `admin_notices`:
https://digwp.com/2016/05/wordpress-admin-notices/

And a similar question:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231010/remove-update-nags-for-non-admins

And a plugin to do it:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-update-nag/

Comment: It remove only admin dont user